# I want to have the <kbd> tags for my blog written in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I write and publish my blog with org-mode and org-page. The thing is that I want to write about Emacs and, I would like to have the keystrokes highlighted as Stack Exchange does with the `<kbd>` tag. Getting this: <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> instead of something else!

In which way or how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here’s what I use for [my blog](http://endlessparentheses.com).

```
(define-key org-mode-map "\C-ck" #'endless/insert-key)
(defun endless/insert-key (key)
  "Ask for a key then insert its description.
Will work on both org-mode and any mode that accepts plain html."
  (interactive "kType key sequence: ")
  (let* ((is-org-mode (derived-mode-p 'org-mode))
         (tag (if is-org-mode
                  "@@html:<kbd>%s</kbd>@@"
                "<kbd>%s</kbd>")))
    (if (null (equal key "\r"))
        (insert
         (format tag (help-key-description key nil)))
      (insert (format tag ""))
      (forward-char (if is-org-mode -8 -6)))))
```

Invoke it by calling `C-c k`.

1. It will prompt you for a key just like `C-h k` would do.
2. It inserts that key sorrounded in escaped `<kbd>` tags.
3. If you just hit `RET`, it will insert the tags and leave point
   inside (instead of inserting any key), so you can type more
   complicated keys.
4. It even has some code to make it usable outside of `org-mode`!

Comment: your blog seems cool, btw. You write it on org-mode right? how do you publish it?

Comment: @JorgeArayaNavarro I use a heavily patched version of [ox-jekyll](https://github.com/yoshinari-nomura/org-octopress/blob/master/ox-jekyll.el). I've been meaning to blog about it, but the patch has 200 lines of code, so it's proven to be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: What's the difference between `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c k") #'endless/insert-key)` and `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c k") 'endless/insert-key)`?

Comment: @JorgeArayaNavarro See my answer to [this comment](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/2708?noredirect=1)

Comment: Nice. And if you want each individual key in the sequence as a separate tag, just change `(help-key-description key nil)` to `(mapconcat 'identity (split-string (help-key-description key nil)) "</kbd><kbd>")`

Comment: Is there something similar for output to LaTeX?