# How note emacs shortcuts in kbd-style?

Tags: keyboard

Emacs keyboard shortcuts are often written as inline code like `C-c C-p`.

How should this be written in kbd-style?

1. <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-p</kbd>
2. <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd>
3. <kbd>C-c</kbd>+<kbd>C-p</kbd>
4. <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> **>** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
6. or something else?

Version 5 is taken from https://keycombiner.com/collections/emacs/

Comment: See the [Emacs manual node on key sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-p</kbd>

This is my preference.  You can generate it easily with this:

```el
(defun my-insert-kbd (keyseq)
  "Read key sequence, and insert it with <kbd> markup."
  ;; Simplified from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2208
  (interactive "kType key sequence: ")
  (insert "<kbd>"
          (mapconcat (lambda (s)
                       (replace-regexp-in-string "<" "&lt;" s))
                     (split-string (help-key-description keyseq nil))
                     "</kbd><kbd>")
          "</kbd>"))
```

> 2. <kbd>C-c C-p</kbd>

Still understandable.

> 3. <kbd>C-c</kbd>+<kbd>C-p</kbd>

Understandable, but no longer like the Emacs notation.

> 4. <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

Gosh, no.  Certain to cause confusion.

> 5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> **>** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

Fairly understandable, but nothing like the Emacs notation.

Emacs notation should be used for consistency, so that's (1) or (2).

Comment: that is a handy snippet

Comment: Combined with the [Edit with Emacs](https://github.com/stsquad/emacs_chrome#readme) browser extension, it makes it very easy to use that markup for Q&As here at E.S.